# Can't create project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I downloaded Visual Studio Code from the Software Center, but when I go to File, there is no option to create a project. I only have the options of creating a file or Workspace. Isn't that a rather important detail? There is no option to create a Project. How can such a deficient version be released?

Answer (score 1):

From the article [Setting up Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-do-i-create-and-run-a-new-project):

> #### How do I create and run a new project?
>
> VS Code doesn't include a traditional **File** > **New Project** dialog or pre-installed project templates. You'll need to add [additional components](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/additional-components) and scaffolders depending on your development interests. With scaffolding tools like [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and the multitude of modules available through the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) package manager, you're sure to find appropriate templates and tools to create your projects.

Comment: Thank you for that information.